# Custom Post Type links not working

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm wanting to make an employee page populated from a custom post type called "Employees".  It lists http://www.domain.com/employees/joe/ as the permalink but the the actual page shows up as unavailable.  Am I missing something on the taxonomy side?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can follow this link already answered.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/379877/134743

Answer (score 2):

Answering it because I just figured it out, but after quite a bit of googling, nothing came up, so hopefully this helps somebody.

Reset the permalinks!

For some reason, if you create a custom post type after you initially set your permalink structure, it needs to be reset.  Go to your settings/permalinks, set them to default, save, and then set them back how you want, save, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The permalink structure needs resetting because this regenerates the rewrite rules within wordpress, allowing the different URL segment structures to be properly recognised and processed.

Wordpress rewriting works very well, but getting around it for custom post types, custom taxonomies etc. has added an extra set of needs to the system, which are slowly being improved.  The custom rewrite system was added, and it's continued development is gradually making it easier to tackle issues like this.

In many cases, a custom taxonomy is the easiest way to go.